# ImportError: No module named texttable (igraph, py2exe,cx freeze/gui2exe)

Tags: module, py2exe, igraph, cx-freeze, gui2exe

I've spent 2 days trying to solve this problem and I'm getting nowhere.

I try to get an executable from my python script.

Script is running with no issues. I build graphs in it by using igraph which is my favorite choice for this task.

After compiling my script I get the results as expected (Dist folder with my exe and its stuff in it)

When I try to run the exe I get this annoying error message:

```
 File "igraph\__init__.pyc", line 36, in <module>
 File "igraph\clustering.pyc", line 38, in <module>
 File "igraph\summary.pyc", line 36, in <module>
 File "igraph\vendor\__init__.pyc", line 33, in vendor_import
ImportError: No module named texttable
```

I checked many threads related to ImportError. I went in the folder containing texttable and IT'S THERE! It's not missing! I've tryed something with changing the path but still no succes.

at the beginning of my script I have:

```
import re
import os
import csv
import math
from igraph import *
import thread
import unicodedata
from time import sleep
import wx.grid as gridlib
import sys
import Tkinter
from Tkinter import *
```

I have tryed `from igraph import Graph` but it would still look for that TEXTTABLE.

I've tried using py2exe, cx freeze and also the nice Gui interface to them GUI2exe. No luck. Same Error whatever I try.

I'm sorry if the solution is obvious. I'm not a pro. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`igraph` is importing `texttable` dynamically, so the freezing tools don't know that they need to copy the module in.

In cx_Freeze, you could add `igraph.vendor` to 'packages' ([see the docs](http://cx_freeze.readthedocs.org/en/latest/distutils.html)) to force it to copy everything from that package. There's probably a similar option for py2exe.

Alternatively, if you put `import igraph.vendor.texttable` somewhere in the code, the freezing tools will pick that up and know to include it.

Comment: Your solution did work and it was very easy to understand. Thank you so much! :)